# Сохранение результата работы двух пауков Scrapy в один JSON

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

День добрый!

Имеется сайт, состоящий из страниц "списков":
https://www.noah-conference.com/attendees/?confyear=&atype=&columnname=&term=&records=50&sort=&pageno=1
C Данного сайта необходимо спарсить информацию со страницы-списка+зайти по каждой ссылке из списка и спарсить так же оттуда информацию.
Как поступить, если нужно чтоб информация с основной страницы+информация с ссылки хранились в одном json объекте?

У меня выходит такой результат:

```
[
{"status": "CFO"},
{"status": "MD / Partner"},
{"status": "CEO"},]
[
{
"name": "Marco Rodzynek",
"link": "https:\/\/www.noah-conference.com\/attendee\/marco-rodzynek\/",
"company": "NOAH Advisors",
"company_link": "No company link",
"category": "Advisory \/ Financial",
"linkedin_url": "https:\/\/ch.linkedin.com\/pub\/marco-
 rodzynek\/2\/bab\/33",
},
{
"name": "Christian Goettsch",
"link": "https:\/\/www.noah-conference.com\/attendee\/christian-goettsch\/",
"company": "Experteer",
"company_link": "https:\/\/www.noah-conference.com\/company\/experteer\/",
"category": "No category",
"linkedin_url": "http:\/\/de.linkedin.com\/pub\/christian-
 goettsch\/0\/153\/540",
},
{
"name": "Roman Bach",
"link": "https:\/\/www.noah-conference.com\/attendee\/roman-bach\/",
"company": "JamesEdition",
"company_link": "https:\/\/www.noah-
 conference.com\/company\/jamesedition\/",
"category": "Consumer Internet",
"linkedin_url": "https:\/\/www.linkedin.com\/in\/romanbach",
 },]
```

Но нужно примерно так:

```
 [{
"name": "Marco Rodzynek",
"status": "CFO",
"link": "https:\/\/www.noah-conference.com\/attendee\/marco-rodzynek\/",
"company": "NOAH Advisors",
"company_link": "No company link",
"category": "Advisory \/ Financial",
"linkedin_url": "https:\/\/ch.linkedin.com\/pub\/marco-
  rodzynek\/2\/bab\/33",
  },]
```

Код моего паука(первая страница стоит для примера)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import MainPageItems


class PageSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'test'
start_urls = ['https://www.noah-conference.com/attendees/?confyear=&atype=&columnname=&term=&records=50&sort=&pageno=1']
allowed_domains = ['noah-conference.com']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('attendee/')), callback='parse_attendee'),
)


def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.noah-conference.com/attendees/?confyear=&atype=&columnname=&term=&records=50&sort=&pageno=1', callback=self.parse_item)


def parse_item(self, response):
    all = response.xpath('//tr')
    for main_info in all:
        Item = MainPageItems()
        Item['name'] = main_info.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
        Item['link'] = main_info.xpath('td[1]/a[contains(@class, "attendee-name-link")]/@href').extract_first(
            default='No link')
        Item['company'] = main_info.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
        Item['company_link'] = main_info.xpath(
            'td[2]/a[contains(@class, "attendee-name-link")]/@href').extract_first(
            default='No company link')
        Item['category'] = main_info.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first(default='No category')
        Item['linkedin_url'] = main_info.xpath(
            'td[4]/a[contains(@class, "sprite linkedin color-links-attendee-list")]/@href').extract_first(
            default='No linkedin link')
        yield Item

def parse_attendee(self, response):
    Item = MainPageItems()
    Item['status'] = response.xpath('//h4[@class="left-attendee"][1]/text()').extract_first()
    yield Item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Вдруг кому-то еще поможет.

```
def parse(self, response):
    all = response.xpath('//tr')
    for main_info in all:
        Item = MainPageItems()
        Item['name'] = main_info.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
        Item['link'] = main_info.xpath('td[1]/a[contains(@class, "attendee-name-link")]/@href').extract_first(
            default='No link')
        Item['company'] = main_info.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
        Item['company_link'] = main_info.xpath(
            'td[2]/a[contains(@class, "attendee-name-link")]/@href').extract_first(
            default='No company link')
        Item['category'] = main_info.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract_first(default='No category')
        Item['linkedin_url'] = main_info.xpath(
            'td[4]/a[contains(@class, "sprite linkedin color-links-attendee-list")]/@href').extract_first(
            default='No linkedin link')
        Item['year_09'] = main_info.xpath('td[5]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_10'] = main_info.xpath('td[6]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_11'] = main_info.xpath('td[7]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_12'] = main_info.xpath('td[8]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_13'] = main_info.xpath('td[9]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_14'] = main_info.xpath('td[10]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_15_lon'] = main_info.xpath('td[11]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_15'] = main_info.xpath('td[12]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_16_ber'] = main_info.xpath('td[13]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_16_lon'] = main_info.xpath('td[14]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        Item['year_17'] = main_info.xpath('td[15]/i/@class').extract_first(default=' ')
        if Item['link'] is not 'No link':
            yield scrapy.Request(url=Item['link'], meta={'item': Item}, callback=self.parse_attendee, dont_filter=True)
        else:
            Item['position'] = 'No info'
            Item['bio'] = 'No bio'
            Item['all_info'] = 'No info'
            yield Item

def parse_attendee(self, response):
    Item = response.meta['item']
    Item['position'] = response.xpath('//h4[@class="left-attendee"][1]/text()').extract_first()
    Item['bio'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="attendee-container-description"]/p/text()').extract_first(
        default='No bio')
    Item['all_info'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col span_6"][2]//text()').extract_first(
        default='No info')
    yield Item
```